# Why won't this cast?

Tags: java, oop, casting, tree, subclass

So I have a class:

```
public static class AVLTreeNode <E extends Comparable<E>> extends BST.TreeNode<E> {
    protected int height;

    public AVLTreeNode(E e) {
        super(e);
    }
}
```

That extends another class:

```
public static class TreeNode<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    protected E element;
    protected TreeNode<E> left;
    protected TreeNode<E> right;

    public TreeNode(E e) {
        element = e;
    }
}
```

And I am creating an `ArrayList` of type `TreeNode`, and trying to cast it to `AVLTreeNode`:

```
public void balancePath(E e) {
    ArrayList<TreeNode<E>> path = path(e);
    for (int i = path.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        AVLTreeNode<E> a = (AVLTreeNode<E>)(path.get(i));
    //continued code not important...
```

Note that my path method returns an `ArrayList` of type `TreeNode<E>`. But when I try to cast the node that I get at position i in the list to `AVLTreeNode<E>` (a subtype of `TreeNode`) I get a `ClassCastException`.

What is the problem here?

*Edit* Here is the full stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.jeffsite.chapter27.BinarySearchTree$TreeNode cannot be cast to com.jeffsite.chapter29.AVLTree$AVLTreeNode
at com.jeffsite.chapter29.AVLTree.balancePath(AVLTree.java:102)
at com.jeffsite.chapter29.AVLTree.insert(AVLTree.java:19)
at com.jeffsite.chapter29.TestAVLTree.main(TestAVLTree.java:10)
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Post your entire exception, including stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a safe thing to cast because it is true that every `AVLTreeNode` is a `TreeNode`, but it is not necessarily true that every `TreeNode` is a `AVLTreeNode`. You could your `List` only hold `AVLTreeNode`(s), by changing from

```
ArrayList<TreeNode<E>> path = path(e);
```

to

```
List<AVLTreeNode<E>> path = path(e);
```

**But** I you should program to an interface (that's why `List` instead of `ArrayList`), so I think you really want

```
List<TreeNode<E>> path = path(e);
```

and then you can use

```
TreeNode<E> a = path.get(i);
```

And if you must know

```
if (a instanceof AVLTreeNode) {
  // now you can cast a
 AVLTreeNode<E> b = (AVLTreeNode<E>) a;
}
```

Comment: AHA! It worked.. Thank you so much! I just checked to make sure a is an instance of AVLTreeNode. And then I created b and used that for my operations..

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the what path returns. If the the path method/func returns a List of TreeNode then the conversion is not possible as the AVLTreeNode has extra params involved.

You can create the ArrayList or List of AVLTreeNode which should help solve the problem at hand (Only in the case path (method) returns the same).

```
ArrayList<AVLTreeNode<E>> path = path(e);
```

Comment: path returns an ArrayList of type TreeNode

Comment: So in that case the cast will cause a problem. As every AVLTreeNode is a TreeNode but not the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the path method, this dummy method works:

```
public ArrayList<? extends TreeNode<E>> path(E e) {
        AVLTreeNode<E> tn = new AVLTreeNode<E>(e);
        ArrayList<AVLTreeNode<E>> list = new ArrayList<AVLTreeNode<E>>();
        list.add(tn);
        return list;
    }
```